# toilet seat lid/cover loose

Tags: toilet

I have an elongated toilet. My toilet seat cover has come out. The seat is well secured in place. How do I attach cover back to seat? Do I need longer pins to put through the holes shown below? but I don't see broken pins...where can I buy those pins?

[image]
[image]

Comment: where are the original pins ?

Comment: i have no idea, did find then on the floor

Comment: currently there are pins which are holding the toilet seat...but they seem to be too small to hold the cover as well the seat

Comment: what are those pings called? where can i buy those?

Comment: Buy a new seat.

Comment: any particular recommendation? I am in USA

Comment: american standard slow close elongated, can get it at HD.  I use these on toto toilets.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/American-Standard-5503A00B-020-CLOSE-ELONGATED/dp/B084JHKFCW?th=1 - is this the one?